# Integer Solutions to linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find integer solutions to the system: $\begin{bmatrix} 9 & 0 & 7 & -5 \\0 & 9 & 1 & 7\end{bmatrix}x = b$, where $b$ can be any of the following $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \pm 2 \\ \pm 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} \pm 2 \\ \pm 1 \end{bmatrix}$ denotes the four possible combinations.

I have that an initial solution is $x = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{9} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-1}{9} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and the null space is $\{\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ -8 \\ 9 \\ 9 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 54 \\ 0 \\ -63 \\ 9 \end{bmatrix}\}$

Comment: Have you tried parametrising the solutions?

Comment: I see 18 possible values for $b$.